# Как разделить список строк на разные списки

Tags: python

Есть список строк `['1;150;40;380']`.
Как из него, сделать так:

```py
x = [1]
y = [150]
z = [40]
a = [380]
```

Comment: Начнем с того, что в питоне разделитель элементов в списке не семиколон, а запятая.

Comment: Я понимаю, просто такое в условии именно так указано.

Comment: Покажите ваше условие, а то вопрос вообще непонятный.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос (а вопрос мутный и понять его сложно) нужно сделать так: `x = lst[0]; y = lst[1]; z = lst[3]; a = lst[4]`

Comment: Где lst — имя вашего списка.

Comment: Буквально есть один файл, с информацией в таком виде 1;150;40;380 Необходимо с помощью указанных данных произвести расчет и перезаписать в другой файл, и при вызове readline, эта строка читается именно как ['1;150;40;380']

Comment: Да, верно поняли

Comment: У вас в файле одна строка? вы уверены, что используете readline, а не readlines?

Comment: Да действительно открывал через readlines, спасибо вам за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из ваших комментарий к вопросу, когда в первой (может быт, единственной) строке вашего файла будет `1;150;40;380`, а вы хотите получить **не 4 списки** (по одному из этих чисел), а просто эти числа, то возможно так:

```
with open('input.txt') as fin:
    line = fin.readline()            # НЕ readlines(), a readline()
 
line = line.strip().split(';')       # удалим знак конца строки и разбиваем в список
lst_n_int = map(int, line)           # генерируем целые числа (int) из строк в списке

x, y, z, a = lst_n_int

# Тест
print(x, y, z, a)
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> 1 150 40 380
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

Ответ на ваш оригинальный вопрос, не учитывая ваших комментариев к нему, бы выл такой:

```
lst_1_str = ['1;150;40;380']                     #  ваш список (с 1 элементом типа str)
lst_n_str = lst_1_str[0].split(';')              #  n элементов (типа str)
lst_n_int = [[int(el)] for el in lst_n_str]      #  список из n списков по 1 числу

x, y, z, a = lst_n_int

# Тест
print(x, y, z, a)
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> [1] [150] [40] [380]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ну типа однострочник:

```py
lst = ['1;150;40;380']
x, y, z, a = [[int(x)] for x in lst[0].split(';')]
print(x, y, z, a)
```

Вывод:

```
[1] [150] [40] [380]
```